# Как отправить @drawable image file (GIF) через MMS?

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, android

Я использую анимационные GIF изображения, которые, как я понял, необходимо хранить в @drawable, чтобы хоть как-то с ними работать из приложения.

Отображать их в ImageView я могу.

Возникла необходимость отправлять их через MMS.

Использую следующий код:

```
Uri auri = Uri.fromFile( new File("@drawable/" + animationFile ) );
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
i.putExtra("address", editPhone.getText().toString());
i.putExtra("sms_body", "Here we go");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, auri);
i.setType("image/gif");
startActivity(i);
```

В итоге изображение к сообщению не цепляется ни в эмуляторе, ни в устройстве. Я исследовал массу ресурсов с описанием всяких способов, но ничего дельного не нашел.

Итак, вопросы - варианты решения:

1. Можно ли к сообщению прикрепить GIF, располагающийся в сети? Через `http://www....`?
2. Можно ли как-то использовать fileprovider? Описание в сети есть, но как нужные изображения запихать в НЕКИЙ internal storage??? И вообще вызов функции `FileProvider.getUriForFile` вызывает целый ряд исключений, перечислять которые не буду...
3. Можно ли отправлять MMS самому? Без использования встроенного в телефон ПО?

СПАСИБО!

Comment: 1. Можно. Но нужно будет предварительно скачать файл на дивайс.    
2. Не думаю, что тут уместно использовать что-то подобное.    
3. Нельзя. Если бы было можно, то это было бы АхМедведьКакойКритической уязвимостью (натихаря отправлять ММС на платные номера, например)